# Trouble converting String to Date in Java

Tags: java, date, data-conversion

I have a date in a `String`:

```
String string = "16.03.2017, 09:22";
```

I'm trying to convert it to a `Date`.

```
Locale russianLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setRegion("RU").build();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm",russianLocale).parse(string);
```

No matter what value I give to this function, it prints date "Mon Dec 26 09:22:00 MSK 2016". The time value is current, but the date is always the same.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect. Use this line to replace the one in your code:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm", russianLocale).parse(string);
```

---

Full code:

```
private static Date convertStringToDate(String string) {
    Date date = new Date();
    Locale russianLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setRegion("RU").build();
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm", russianLocale).parse(string);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting pattern is incorrect. The codes used are case-sensitive. The `dd` and `yyyy` should be lowercase.

Also you are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone.

And you are using the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use the modern java.time classes instead. Hundreds of existing Questions and Answers on Stack Overflow on this topic. Search for class names ZoneId, LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime, and DateTimeFormatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu, HH:mm" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(  "16.03.2017, 09:22" , f );
```

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the format in SimpleDateFormat cunstructor. You have used a wrong formatter  DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm. So just replace it with "dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"

private static Date convertStringToDate(String string)  {
        Date date = new Date();
        Locale russianLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setRegion("RU").build();
        try {
             date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm",russianLocale).parse(string);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }